# Best way to copy a file from Windows machine to Linux machine using java

Tags: java, linux

My requirement is to copy a file that is on windows machine to Linux machine using the IP, User name and password of the windows machine using java code. I have the java code running on linux machine. I want to know the best way to achieve this. What is the procedure to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/) to access a Windows share from Java on Linux or Windows.

Comment: Hi Peter Lawrey, I tried your suggestion I could access the files on Windows. But I'm facing issues accessing files on Linux machine. I have posted the details in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110523/create-network-share-via-samba-on-linux-machine-via-cli

Answer (score 1):

Your code is running on the Windows machine, right?  The most secure way would be to use SSH. http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ looks like a pretty good implementation.  It's used by ant, maven. etc, to do the same thing.

On the other hand, if you're not creating a new build system, could I suggest that perhaps your build system (ant/maven/gradle) should be copying your files around for you?

Comment: Well, this answer still works, but you'll have to set up an SSH server on your windows machine.  I like cygwin's SSH server.